# Creating a nested dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file and Im trying to create a nested dictionary that looks like this:

```
contacts = {"Tom": {"name": "Tom Techie",
                    "phone": "123 123546",
                    "email": "tom@tom.fi",
                    "skype": "skypenick"},

            "Mike": {"name": "Mike Mechanic",
                     "phone": "000 123546",
                     "email": "mike@mike.fi",
                     "skype": "-Mike-M-"}}
```

etc

And this is what I have written:

```
file = open("csv","r")
d = {}
for i in file:

    f = i.strip()
    x = f.split(";")

    if x[4] != "":
        d.update({x[0] : {"name":x[1],
                      "phone":x[2],
                      "email":x[3],
                      "skype":x[4]}})

    else:
        d.update ({x[0] : {"name": x[1],
                       "phone": x[2],
                       "email": x[3]}})
```

However it prints the dict as a normal dictionary with the updates as keys when they should be like stated above.

EDIT:
First lines of the csv:

```
key;name;phone;email;skype
Tom;Tom Techie;123 123546;tom@tom.fi;skypenick
Mike;Mike Mechanic;000 123456;mike@mike.fi;-Mike-M-
Archie;Archie Architect;050 987654;archie@archie
```

Comment: Your question has insufficient infomration to a) run the code, b) reproduce the problem, c) help you.

Comment: You should at least provide the first few lines of the csv file

Comment: Edited first lines of cv to opening post

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.read_csv()` and `to_dict()`:

```
import pandas as pd

contacts = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';').set_index('key').to_dict(orient='index')
```

Yields:

```
{'Tom': {'name': 'Tom Techie', 'phone': '123 123546', 'email': 'tom@tom.fi', 'skype': 'skypenick'}, 'Mike': {'name': 'Mike Mechanic', 'phone': '000 123456', 'email': 'mike@mike.fi', 'skype': '-Mike-M-'}, 'Archie': {'name': 'Archie Architect', 'phone': '050 987654', 'email': 'archie@archie', 'skype': nan}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the `pandas` answer, but if you don't want a 3rd party library, use the built-in `csv` module:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

D = {}
with open('csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=';')
    for line in r:
        name = line['key']
        del line['key']
        D[name] = dict(line)

pprint(D)
```

Output:

```
{'Archie': {'email': 'archie@archie',
            'name': 'Archie Architect',
            'phone': '050 987654',
            'skype': None},
 'Mike': {'email': 'mike@mike.fi',
          'name': 'Mike Mechanic',
          'phone': '000 123456',
          'skype': '-Mike-M-'},
 'Tom': {'email': 'tom@tom.fi',
         'name': 'Tom Techie',
         'phone': '123 123546',
         'skype': 'skypenick'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to achieve your goal:

```
file = """key;name;phone;email;skype
Tom;Tom Techie;123 123546;tom@tom.fi;skypenick
Mike;Mike Mechanic;000 123456;mike@mike.fi;-Mike-M-
Archie;Archie Architect;050 987654;archie@archie""".splitlines()

d = {}
h = None
for i in file: # works the same for your csv-file
    # first row == header, store in h
    if h is None:
        h = i.strip().split(";")[1:]
        continue # done for first row

    x = i.strip().split(";")

    # zip pairs the read in line with the header line to get tuples
    # wich are fed into the dict constructor that creates the inner dict
    d[x[0]] = dict(zip(h,x[1:]+[""])) # no default for skype

    # use this instead if you want the skype key always present with empty default
    # d[x[0]] = dict(zip(h,x[1:]+[""]))  

print(d)
```

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) discards the elements of the longer list - you won't need any checks for that.

Output:

```
{'Tom':   {'name': 'Tom Techie', 'phone': '123 123546', 
           'email': 'tom@tom.fi', 'skype': 'skypenick'}, 
 'Mike':   {'name': 'Mike Mechanic', 'phone': '000 123456', 
            'email': 'mike@mike.fi', 'skype': '-Mike-M-'}, 
 'Archie': {'name': 'Archie Architect', 'phone': '050 987654', 
            'email': 'archie@archie'}}
```

If you use the commented line, the data will get a default value of `''` for the skype - works only b/c skype is the last element of the splitted line

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension! Assuming the data is something like [image: this here...]

```
with open("df.csv", "r") as file:
  d = {x.split(";")[0]:{
      "name": x.split(";")[2], 
      "phone": x.split(";")[3],
      "email": x.split(";")[1], 
      "skype": x.split(";")[4][:-1] # Slice off trailing newline
  } for x in file}
  d.pop("")
```

We want to open files using `with` whenever possible to benefit from Python's context management. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ for fundamental understanding of the `with` statement.

Since the key `""` only appears once at the head of the csv, we can pop it at the end and avoid performing a comparison at every iteration. A dict comprehension accomplishes the same thing you wanted to achieve with `d.update`.

More about comprehensions: 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Edit: refactoring to remove the repetitive calls to `.split` can look something like this:

```
def line_to_dict(x, d):
  x = x.split(";")
  d[x[0]] = {
      "name": x[2], 
      "phone": x[3],
      "email": x[1], 
      "skype": x[4][:-1] # Slice off trailing newline
  }

with open("df.csv", "r") as file:
  d = {}
  for x in file:
    line_to_dict(x, d)
  d.pop("")
```